# PHP-Open-Source-Saver / jwt-auth Invalidate and Blacklist JWT Token

Tags: php, jwt, laravel-8, php-8

I have setup a Laravel 8.* project in PHP8.0 environment on an Apache2 server.  I installed the new `PHP-Open-Source-Saver / jwt-auth`  repo and implemented the necessary Middleware to validate the jwt tokens as well as a JwtController to generate a jwt token on login and refresh if needed.

Api requests are authenticated with:

```
$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
```

So far everything worked as described on the side of the box, except for the `invalidation` and `blacklisting` of jwt tokens.

My jwt config blacklist keys are set in env as:

```
JWT_BLACKLIST_ENABLED=true
JWT_BLACKLIST_GRACE_PERIOD=0
```

I tried the instructions and all of the below methods, each at least twice:

```
public function jwt_logout(Request $request)
{
    //get bearer token
    $token = $request->bearerToken();

    if (! isset($token) ) {
        return response()->json([
                'success' => false,
                'message' => 'Token is not set, please retry action or login.'
            ]);
    }

    //Invalidate and blacklist methods
    try {
        //JWTAuth::invalidate(JWTAuth::getToken());
        //JWTAuth::invalidate($request->bearerToken());
        //auth("api")->invalidate(true);
        //JWTAuth::invalidate($request->token);
        //JWTAuth::parseToken()->invalidate();
        //\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::setToken($token)->invalidate(true);
        
        JWTAuth::setToken($token)->invalidate(true);

        //auth("api")->logout(true);
        //JWTAuth::invalidate(true);
        //\JWTAuth::manager()->invalidate(new \PHPOpenSourceSaver\JWTAuth\Token($token), $forceForever = true);

        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'User has been logged out'
        ]);
    } catch (JWTException $exception) {
        return response()->json([
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'Sorry, user cannot be logged out'
        ], Response::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

But every time I tried using a jwt token that was blacklisted after running above method, it still allows authentication of the user. NO JWTBLACKLISTEDEXCEPTION. No errors. The only thing that stops authentication is when a jwt token expires.

Can someone help to give insight into how to `invalidate` and `blacklist` a jwt token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I found my answer. By default the package has [disabled the showing of a blacklist exceptions](https://github.com/PHP-Open-Source-Saver/jwt-auth/issues/84).

I just had to set `JWT_SHOW_BLACKLIST_EXCEPTION=1` in my .env and now it works. Not reading package forum issues was my oversight.